# Excel Offset Row and Cell

Tags: offset, cells

I have vba code which will compare 2 different excel workbook sheets (wb1 is always the same, wb2 is used to compare data in column A of sheet1). If a match is found, it will copy the entire row or rows to a new worksheet in wb1.
The code works great, however I also need to copy the data of 2 cells which are always 5 rows down and 5 cells to the right of each 'matched' row, these need to be added to the end cell of the row pasted into the new worksheet in wb1.  I think offset is the best way, but although I quite good with excel, I need a little help if possible with this part.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try `=R[RowOffset]C[ColumnOffset]` to use **relative** position.
In your case: `=R[5]C[5]`.
By the way, specifying both of them is not mandatory, you can leave one of them without offset and the excel will use the current cell value.
for example: `=RC[-2]` will retrieve the cell positioned two column to the left on the same row.